# Add values to an object from another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, object

So i have this scope with a predefined equipment:

```
$scope.equipment = [
    {slot: 7, colspan: 2, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 0, colspan: 2, rowspan: 2},
    {slot: 10, colspan: 2, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 8, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 9, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 6, colspan: 2, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 17, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 18, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 1, colspan: 2, rowspan: 4},
    {slot: 19, colspan: 2, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 4, colspan: 2, rowspan: 4},
    {slot: 5, colspan: 2, rowspan: 4},
    {slot: 14, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 15, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 2, colspan: 2, rowspan: 2},
    {slot: 16, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 15, colspan: 1, rowspan: 1},
    {slot: 3, colspan: 2, rowspan: 2}
  ];
```

As you can see, each slot has its own colspan and rowspan.

Than i have the equipment items array of objects:

```
    $scope.equipmentItems = [
     {
        "id": 282,
        "upgrade": 15,
        "bind": 1,
        "slot": 0,
        "name": "Archridium Headpiece (BL)"
    },
     {
        "id": 147,
        "upgrade": 15,
        "bind": 1,
        "slot": 1,
        "name": "Archridium Suit (BL)"
    },
     {
        "id": 192,
        "upgrade": 15,
        "bind": 1,
        "slot": 2,
        "name": "Archridium Hands (BL)"
    },
     {
        "id": 237,
        "upgrade": 15,
        "bind": 1,
        "slot": 3,
        "name": "Archridium Shoes (BL)"
    },
     {
        "id": 3706,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 4
    },
     {
        "id": 3707,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 5
    },
     {
        "id": 3622,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 6
    },
     {
        "id": 408,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 7,
        "name": "Amulet Of Pain +7",
        "description": "Protect you from enemy's attacks and to give more chance to do Critical Attacks. "
    },
     {
        "id": 3194,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 8,
        "name": "Ring of Luck +3",
        "description": "Increases your Critical Hit Rate."
    },
     {
        "id": 3193,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 9,
        "name": "Critical Ring +3",
        "description": "Increases your Critical Attack Damage."
    },
     {
        "id": 2371,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 1,
        "slot": 10,
        "name": "Astral Board Card - K Red Crystal Edition",
        "description": "A mysterious card that summons Astral Board, one of the valuable Honorable Age's legacies and the essence of Core Technology. - K Red Crystal Edition_$4#(Right click to use) "
    },
     {
        "id": 3607,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 13
    },
     {
        "id": 3607,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 14
    },
    : {
        "id": 3604,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 15
    },
     {
        "id": 3604,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 16
    },
     {
        "id": 2568,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 4,
        "slot": 17,
        "name": "Leth Tyrant's Ring",
        "description": "This ring contains the sealed power of Leth Tyrant, the extraordinary monster created by the Doctor. "
    },
     {
        "id": 3184,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 4,
        "slot": 18,
        "name": "Killian's Ring",
        "description": "This generates powerful energy from the combination of Killian's Dark Energy and the grudge of the Black Cat, the Guardian of Hell."
    },
    "{
        "id": 2228,
        "upgrade": 0,
        "bind": 0,
        "slot": 19,
        "name": "Belt of Damp +4",
        "description": "This belt reduces damage from intensified sword or magic attacks. "
    }
];
```

As you can see each object key is basically the slot id.

Than i use this code

```
      $scope.equipmentItems = _.sortBy($scope.equipmentItems, function(obj) {
    return _.indexOf([7, 0, 10, 8, 9, 6, 17, 18, 1, 19, 4, 5, 14, 13, 2, 16, 15, 3], obj.slot);
  });
```

to sort the equipment items keys to my specific order.

Anyway, what i want is the most performant piece of code that can add the values colspan and rowspan from **$scope.equipment** to **$scope.equipmentItems** WHERE $scope.equipment slot correspond to $scope.equipmentItems slot.

Comment: `equipmentItems` looks odd, in that you're using square brackets around a list of key: value pairs. Shouldn't it be curly brackets instead?

Comment: $scope.equipmentItems is not a valid array of objects.

Comment: `equipment.forEach(function (eq) { var item = equipmentItems[eq.slot]; item. colspan = eq.colspan; item.rowspan = eq.rowspan; })`

Comment: Yeah my bad, i was moddifying a little the code from the api response and add the keys by mistake. Updated.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot set property 'colspan' of undefined. Thats my error in console.

Comment: Only assign `item.colspan` and `item.rowspan` if `item` is present, as in `if (item) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array` functions. Something like this:

```
let merged = equipmentItems.map(item=>{
  item.anotherKey = equipment.find(it=> it.slot == item.slot);
  return item;
});
```

If you don't like this, or you can't use those methods you can use `forEach`

```
equipmentItems.forEach(function(item){
    equipment.forEach(function(item_){
      if(item.slot == item_.slot){
        item.someKey = item_;
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wrong, i don't want to put the slot,colspan,rowspan into the slot but as independent key - value after slot or before, something like that.

Comment: And i do not want to use this ecma script version.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: I suppose so. I thought of using foreach in foreach but thats why i asked a question here is there is something much faster than this.

Comment: @allocen Well if you would have the first array like an object literal like this slots = {"7" : {slot: 7, colspan: 2, rowspan: 1}, ...} you would be able get the data like this slots[item.slot] and the other loop wouldn't be need.